# JQuery, DOMContentLoaded and load events

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to understand why JQuery initiation process uses both `DOMContentLoaded`(**document event**) and `load`(**window event**),

Here is the code: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.js (lines 3418-3429).

Another thing I couldn't understand is the use of `false` as **addEventListener** third argument, I mean according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) the default is already `false` so why they send `false`?.

And finally there is this strange comment:

```
// A fallback to window.onload, that will always work
window.addEventListener("load", func, false);
```

I couldn't find the **window.onload** event in the code, so why do they say that **window.addEventListener** is a fallback when there is no **window.onload**?

**EDIT:**

About the `false` third argument I do understand now I didn't saw this sentence from the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener):

> Note: useCapture became optional only in more recent versions of the
>   major browsers; for example, it was not optional prior to Firefox 6.
>   You should provide this parameter for broadest compatibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I couldn't find the window.onload event in the code, so why do they say that window.addEventListener is a fallback when there is no window.onload?

`window.addEventListener("load", func, false);` is equivalent to `window.onload`.

The false parameter of `addEventListener` is `useCapture`. From MDN:

> If true, useCapture indicates that the user wishes to initiate capture. After initiating capture, all events of the specified type will be dispatched to the registered listener before being dispatched to any EventTarget beneath it in the DOM tree. Events which are bubbling upward through the tree will not trigger a listener designated to use capture. See DOM Level 3 Events for a detailed explanation. If not specified, useCapture defaults to false.

Comment: Rory, thank you for your answer I understand the use of false now, but can you explain why in the comment they say "that will always work" what cases for example window.onload won't work?, and why using "load" and "DOMContentLoaded" events?

Comment: @AvielFadida you have it the wrong way around. `DOMContentLoaded` is not fully supported in very old browsers, so they use `window.onload` as a fallback.

Comment: So if I understand they prefer `DOMContentLoaded` but if its not supported they use window.onload?

Comment: Just a last thing to ask, why in the comment they say "that will always work" I mean why should `window.onload` won't work?

Comment: No, again you've got it the wrong way around. `window.onload` will *always* work, that's why it is the fallback.

Comment: So if `window.addEventListener("load")` is not supported window.onload will always be supported?

Comment: No, `window.addEventListerne('load')` ***is*** `window.onload`. It means if `document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded")` is not supported, use `window.addEventListener( "load")`.

Comment: Now I understand, thank you for being patient with me.